# Regex to remove all two letter words but exclude certain

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I am attempting to remove all one or two letter words in R with this regular expression:

```
\\b\\w{1,2}\\b
```

But I also want to exclude certain two letter words from the removal, e.g. IT.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can add a negative lookahead before `\\b(?!IT|BT|LO)\\w{1,2}\\b`

Comment: Robin’s suggestion notwithstanding I wouldn’t (only) use regular expressions to solve this problem. Rather, use a two-step approach: tokenise the text (using regex for word boundaries), filter out short words that are not on your inclusion list, and reconstruct the string.